# Can the solutions for the Briggs Rauscher experiment be made ahead of time and stored?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solutions

I will be performing the Briggs Rauscher Oscillating reaction as a part of an investigation into the effect of heat on the antioxidants.

This will require 3 solutions to be mixed together, as shown below, to obtain a reaction which will oscillate between clear to yellow to a dark blue.

Solution A:
- 9%  $\ce{H2O2}$

Solution B:
- Acidified 0.2 M $\ce{KIO3}$ solution

Solution C:
- Solution of soluble starch/Malonic acid/$\ce{MnSO4}$

However, as I will be able to work on this in 45 minute blocks, I am unable to make up the solutions fresh every single time. Hence, I was wondering if it would be possible for me to make up enough solution at the beginning and store them for subsequent trials.

Does anyone know if these solutions can be made ahead of time and stored, without obviously affecting the reaction. If so, how for how long, and are any special conditions eg. refrigeration required?

Comment: Should be no problem, even next day.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just concerned will the starch fall out of solution?